# audio-hal-2-0 not found on booting in android

Tags: android, audio, android-source, porting

I'm building android 9 for the Resenas Rcar-H3 board. The building process is successful. But after flash images into the board, The booting process doesn't work correctly. audioserver is restarted by init process and notify several errors like below:

```
[  737.947862] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2734) exited with status 1
[  737.954674] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 2734) process group...
[  737.962915] libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 2734 in 0ms
[  737.971171] init: Command 'restart vendor.audio-hal-2-0' action=onrestart (<Service 'audioserver' onrestart>:1) took 0ms and failed: service vendor.audio-hal-2-0 not found
[  737.986524] init: Command 'restart audio-hal-2-0' action=onrestart (<Service 'audioserver' onrestart>:2) took 0ms and failed: service audio-hal-2-0 not found
[  742.929725] init: starting service 'audioserver'...
[  742.964835] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2735) exited with status 1
[  742.971523] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 2735) process group...
[  742.979681] libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 2735 in 0ms
[  742.987951] init: Command 'restart vendor.audio-hal-2-0' action=onrestart (<Service 'audioserver' onrestart>:1) took 0ms and failed: service vendor.audio-hal-2-0 not found
[  743.003317] init: Command 'restart audio-hal-2-0' action=onrestart (<Service 'audioserver' onrestart>:2) took 0ms and failed: service audio-hal-2-0 not found
[  747.946500] init: starting service 'audioserver'...
[  747.981024] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2736) exited with status 1
[  747.987697] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'audioserver' (pid 2736) process group...
[  747.995844] libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1041 pid 2736 in 0ms
[  748.004108] init: Command 'restart vendor.audio-hal-2-0' action=onrestart (<Service 'audioserver' onrestart>:1) took 0ms and failed: service vendor.audio-hal-2-0 not found
...
```

Can anyone help me? Thank All!

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you told `init` to start `vendor.audio-hal-2-0` but did not provide the service definition.

In one of your installed `.rc`-files there might be a call like this:

```
start vendor.audio-hal-2-0
```

You should also have a service definition file that looks somewhat like this:

```
service vendor.audio-hal-2-0 /vendor/bin/hw/<binary>
    <options>
```

If you don't then you need to create one and if you do it is probably not installed correctly. You can install additional service files in your `Android.bp` module definition like this:

```
cc_binary {
    [ ... ]
    init_rc: [ "vendor.audio-hal-2-0.rc" ],
    [...]
}
```